# jQuery String Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Having a bit of problem with some syntax trying to insert HTML after an element.

```
$('<div id="newdiv" style="height:' + heightvar +'"></div>').insertAfter('#mydiv');
```

The new div inserts in the correct place but is missing the height property in the style so looks like this.

```
<div id="newdiv" style=""></div>
```

Can you see the problem with my syntax?

Comment: What is the value of `heightvar`?

Comment: Have you alerted `heightvar` to make sure there is a value? I suspect it's empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot the units in your `heightvar` variable.

`heightvar = '10'` would result in a blank style attribute, but `heightvar = '10px'` would not.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. I didn't know that the style would be left blank without the px.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
$('<div id="newdiv">')
.css({height:heightvar})
.insertAfter('#mydiv');
```

Comment: Semantics that have nothing to do with the question. Brandon has correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div id="newdiv" style="height:'+ heightvar +'px">hello</div>').insertAfter('#mydiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the style using jquery function and not templating. Will perform better and is easier to do.

```
var myDiv = $('<div id="newdiv"></div>');
$(myDiv).css('height', heightvar);
myDiv.insertAfter('#mydiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `heightvar` has invalid value. See my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/LXTc8/),

Below code works for me,

```
var heightvar = '0px';

$('<div id="newdiv" style="height:' + heightvar +'"></div>').insertAfter('#mydiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch around the selector. The JQuery function - $() - should be used for selecting the element you want to change. Try:

```
var heightvar = '0px';

$('#mydiv').after('<div id="newdiv" style="height:' + heightvar +'"></div>');
```